# How to extract value from JSON in presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table which has a column named json_dump, it contains data like

```
{
    
    "dataResource": {
        "id": "96cbba38-4df2-4c6c-8ab5-574d8e6b3c00",
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnName": "is_polymorphed",
                "columnType": "BOOLEAN"

            },
            {
            "columnName": "courier_loyalty_period_balance",
        "columnType": "INT"

            }
        ]

    }

}
```

I want to extract all columnName and columnType, but I get null when I do

```
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_dump, '$.dataResource.columns')
FROM table
```

Comment: please note that the json object you attached is invalid, there is an extra comma after `"columnType": "BOOLEAN",`

Answer (score 2):

[`json_extract_scalar`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_extract_scalar) has the following limitation:

> The value referenced by `json_path` must be a scalar (boolean, number or string)

You can try using `JSON_QUERY`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(json_dump) as(
    values ('{
    "dataResource": {
        "id": "96cbba38-4df2-4c6c-8ab5-574d8e6b3c00",
        "columns": [
            {
                "columnName": "is_polymorphed",
                "columnType": "BOOLEAN"
            },
            {
                "columnName": "courier_loyalty_period_balance",
                "columnType": "INT"
            }
        ]
    }
}')
)

-- query
SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_dump, 'lax $.dataResource.columns') cols
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

```
                                                            cols
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"columnName":"is_polymorphed","columnType":"BOOLEAN"},{"columnName":"courier_loyalty_period_balance","columnType":"INT"}]
```

Another option is to use `json_extract`. On top of it you can use `cast` to `array(map(varchar, json))` which then can be unnested:

```sql
-- queru
SELECT cast(JSON_EXTRACT(json_dump, '$.dataResource.columns') as array(map(varchar, json)))
FROM dataset;
```

Comment: How do I unnest from the array map?

Comment: @JohnConstantine can you please update question with desired output, so I can improve the answer. But in short - using `unnest` keyword